# Find a general solution for this recurrence: $a_n = \sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, combinations

Find a general solution for this recurrence:
$$a_n = \sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}$$
when $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 8$.

---

**My attempt to solve it:**

This recurrence isn't a regular one. In order to solve it,
I have tried to count the first elements in this recurrence, which are $$a_1 = 2, a_2 = 8, a_3 = 4, a_4 = \sqrt{32}, a_5 = \sqrt{512} ...,$$ but I didn't find any way to proceed.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try $a_n$ = $2^{b_n}$

Comment: and what is $b_n$?

Comment: I mean how can I find a general solution for $b_n$?

Comment: @RoboYonuomaro using the  given recurrence formula for $a_n$.

Comment: First write the recurrence among $b_n, b_{n-1}, b_{n-2}$  using

Comment: For the record, this is a classical way to compute $$\lim a_n=\sqrt[3]{a_1a_2^2}$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** By taking the log (with respect to any base) of both sides, we can rewrite the recurrence as
$$
\log(a_n) = \frac 12[\log(a_{n-1}) + \log(a_{n-2})]
$$
So, the sequence $b_n := \log(a_n)$ satisfies a linear recurrence.

Answer (score 3):

Taking logs,
and letting
$b_n = \log a_n$,
this becomes
$b_n
=\frac12(b_{n-1}+b_{n-2})
$.

The characteristic polynomial is
$x^2-\frac12 x-\frac12 = 0$
which has roots
$x
=\dfrac{\frac12\pm\sqrt{\frac14+2}}{2}
=\dfrac{\frac12\pm\sqrt{\frac94}}{2}
=\dfrac{\frac12\pm\frac32}{2}
=\dfrac{2, -1}{2}
=1, -\frac12
$
so the solutions are
$b_n = 1$
and
$b_n = (-1/2)^n
$.

As a check
$\frac12(b_{n-1}+b_{n-2})
=\frac12((-1/2)^{n-1}+(-1/2)^{n-2})
=\frac12(-1/2)^{n-2}(-\frac12+1)
=\frac12(-1/2)^{n-2}(\frac12)
=\frac14(-1/2)^{n-2}
=(-1/2)^{n}
$.

Therefore
$b_n = u+v(-1/2)^{n}$
for any reals $u$ and $v$,
so,
$a_n = rs^{(-1/2)^{n}}$
where $r$ and $s$ are 
positive reals
(actually, you can let them be
any types that you can raise to a real power).